# Initial-scale vs. desktop.css+phone.css+tablet.css?

Tags: css, font-size

I just discovered the initial-scale meta attribute.

Previously, I've been using a default.css to define all my styles and sizes (for fonts and elements) so they appear nicely on screen real estates of desktop computers.   Then I might use media queries or PHP to include an phone.css or tablet.css if you're using a phone or tablet, and this will adjust ONLY SIZES for smaller devices.

But now that I've become aware of the concept of initial-scale, should I be using that instead to control sizes of elements?

A very important consequence I'm trying to get at is this...I use to define my font sizes with EM (or REM) units like this:

```
/*desktop.css*/
html{font-size:62.5%;}
p{font-size:1.2em;}
span {font-size:1em;}

/*phone.css*/
html{font-size:125%;}

/*tablet.css*/
html{font-size:100%;}
```

In other words, my phone.css and tablet.css only adjusts the font-size percentage on the html element, and all other elements will scale accordingly on all different devices.  To a certain degree, i do this wiht padding, margins, lineheights and letterspacing.

With the introduction of initial-scale, does that mean EM/REM units are irrelevant for scaling font sizes?  We can stick to the much more intuitive PX units?  And let initial-scale do the rest of the scaling work?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about the em unit is that it should appear the same across devices and screen densities because the actual height is decided by the client.

I also use the initial scale, min scale, and max scales in a few applications, and have found the px unit to work fairly well, so long as you pick a appropriate value for the scale per device.